# How to get the array cell position when using foreach across an array?

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, xsd

I'm still stuck with using arrays in XSD generated classes, as my XML schema is too complex for `xsd2code`, which created generics-based generated classes.

Is their any way to tell the cell number of an array when using `foreach` across it? Is there any way to do so in LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do it in LINQ:

```
foreach (var item in Items.Select((elem, index) => new { Item = elem, Index = index }))
{
    DoStuff(item.Item, item.Index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig for the quick response. Bob.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "cell number" you mean the index of the current item in the array.

If so, the answer is yes.

For a `for` loop, you can declare an integer variable and increment it in each iteration to track the index.

For example:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var thing in things) {
    //...

    index++;
}
```

---

In LINQ, you can call the overloads of `Select` and `Where` that take 2-parameter lambdas, like this:

```
array.Select((elem, index) => whatever);
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks for the quick response. The first way is the common way and I was looking for summat neater. Bob.